# How to generate multiple xml files based on rowcount

Tags: c#, xml, oracle, odp.net

I am able to successfully generate a large xml file for a million records 
 using the below code.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PARTNER_NO FROM T1 WHERE YEAR LIKE '%2011-2012%'";  
XmlWriter myWriter = XmlWriter.Create("C:/Test/BookInfo.xml")  
myWriter.WriteStartDocument(true); 
using(OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))  
  {  
    reader.FetchSize = reader.RowSize * 5000;  
    myWriter.WriteStartElement("master_table");
    while(reader.Read())
      {  
         myWriter.WriteStartElement("partner");  
         myWriter.WriteElementString("partner_no", reader[0].ToString());  
         myWriter.WriteElementString("id","0008");  
         myWriter.WriteEndElement();  
      }  
 }  

 myWriter.WriteEndDocument();  
 myWriter.Flush();  
 myWriter.Close();  
 cmd.Dispose()
```

This is how my xml looks : [image]

I now have a new requirement of generating multiple xml files of 10,000 records each based on the rowcount. 
Any pointers on this? How should I proceed on this? This needs to be done on c#

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a single SQL call:

```
SQL> SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(CONTENT xmlelement("MASTER_TABLE",
  2                                  xmlagg(xmlelement("PARTNER",
  3                                                    XMLELEMENT("PARTNER_NO",
  4                                                               partner_no),
  5                                                    XMLELEMENT("ID", '0008')
  6                                                    )
  7                                        ))
  8                       INDENT) xmltxt
  9    FROM t1
 10   GROUP BY CEIL(ROWNUM/2)-- replace 2 by 10000
 11  ;

XMLTXT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<MASTER_TABLE>
  <PARTNER>
    <PARTNER_NO>00001</PARTNER_NO>
    <ID>0008</ID>
  </PARTNER>
  <PARTNER>
    <PARTNER_NO>00034</PARTNER_NO>
    <ID>0008</ID>
  </PARTNER>
</MASTER_TABLE>
<MASTER_TABLE>
  <PARTNER>
    <PARTNER_NO>00046</PARTNER_NO>
    <ID>0008</ID>
  </PARTNER>
  <PARTNER>
    <PARTNER_NO>00052</PARTNER_NO>
    <ID>0008</ID>
  </PARTNER>
</MASTER_TABLE>
```

For further reading:

- [`XMLELEMENT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions242.htm#i1129193)
- [`XMLAGG`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions235.htm#i1286333)
- [`XMLSERIALIZE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions252.htm#CIHDHGJD)

Comment: Thanks Vincent. But this is the first time I am working on XML and need a bit of c# code of generating multiple xml files on on click of a button.

Comment: I'm not familiar with C#, but you will probably close the file every 10k rows in the loop, then open another one in your original code.

Comment: what should be the out parameter if this is to be written in a stored procedure as I am getting  ` ERROR line 11, col 24, ending_line 11, ending_col 29, Found 'INDENT', Expecting: )`  and how should VERSION ='1.0', encoding="UTF-8" , STANDALONE= YES be shown in the xml file

Comment: This ones not the correct solution I was looking for but even this works for me.. Thanks.